# MySQL is not running after XAMPP installation

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I've installed XAMPP v. 7.0.2-1 and opened localhost successfully, but when I opened phpmyadmin I got the error
Welcome to phpMyAdmin Error

MySQL said: Documentation

Cannot connect: invalid settings.

Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.

phpMyAdmin
tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the 
connection. You should check the host, username and password in your 
configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information 
given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

I tried to fix 
this with editing config.inc.php (changed the authentification type to 
"http" & specified password), but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. Stop all the services from your Xampp Control Panel
2. Change the code in your config.inc.php from

   ```
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
   $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
   ```

to

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'P@ssw0rd';      //-- To the password changed in phpmyadmin
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;   //-- Change this also to fix the problem
```

3. Start your apache and mysql that were stopped. This should help!!

Answer (score 0):

> (changed the authentification type to "http" & specified password), but it did not help.

Nor would I expect it to; the error message you got is about the values for the configuration directives `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']` and `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']`. Changing the auth_type only affects your login method and the 'password' field has no purpose with auth_type cookie or http.

Edit your `config.inc.php` and comment out those two lines (by adding `//` in front of them), then load phpMyAdmin again.

If you wish to use the advanced features which require this controluser, probably the best way is to change the password for that user (you can do this using phpMyAdmin), and edit `config.inc.php` to add that new password and remove the comment marks. If XAMPP didn't create the controluser for you (which would be really strange, since it configured one in `config.inc.php`, leaving you an unusable installation), you can follow the [steps in the documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#phpmyadmin-configuration-storage).